# Display region's blocks into user-profile.tpl.php

Tags: views, blocks, theming

I created a view listing content type called stories. Then I created a block with this view.

In mytheme.info file I have this code :

```
regions[header] = Header
regions[story] = Story
regions[content] = Content
```

**So I put the view into the Story region**

I want to display the region into `user-profile.tpl.php` so I add this code :

```
<?php print render($page['story']); ?>
```

If everything work, it should display all the stories via the view.

I don't know why it does not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to show blocks only on the profile page and not on the user/register or user/login or or user/*/edit, you can use the code for blocks visibility.

```
<?php
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'user' && $user->uid == arg(1) && is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == NULL) )
{
  return TRUE;
}

else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```